# Cloud Functions for Firebase: Project structure multiple self-contained functions

Tags: function, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools, google-cloud-tools

I am trying to create a project structure similar to the following:

```
--firebase-admin-project
  --firebase.json
  --functions
    --anonymous-login
      --node_modules
      --index.js
      --package.json
    --auth-login
      --node_modules
      --index.js
      --package.json
```

The intention  is to do "firebase deploy --only functions" in either the anonymous-login or auth-login folders but the deployment fails.

Currently, "firebase init functions" creates new index.js and package.json files in the functions folder, which is not what I want.

Also, we want to avoid using require to pull all functions into one index.js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `firebase deploy`, it will deploy every function in your project and all files under the functions directory. There is currently no way to select anything less than the entire thing.

**Update**: There is a new feature in the CLI that allows for individual functions and groups of functions to be deployed independently.  The documentation for that is in the [partial deploys](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#partial_deploys) section of the docs.

Comment: can you help. I get a deploy compete in the terminal but when i go to the firebase console and view the functions tab... its blank!?

Comment: Make sure you look inside the correct project. Use `firebase list` to see the project which is currently active. And `firebase use` to select another one in case it's wrong.

Comment: Just see the help ; now you can do it ; try firebase help deploy in CLI

Comment: @TheeBen Yes, that feature is newer than the time this answer was written.

Comment: Yes, just thought in case you havn't noticed, because it's not officially part of the doc yet I think; other than a hint somewhere. cheers

Comment: @TheeBen It's in the doc.  I edited this answer and linked to it.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I just realized I'm commenting under the wrong topic altogether. My bad. You are absolutely right

Answer (score 4):

```
firebase deploy --only functions:<any function>
```

Firebase has started allowing developers to deploy specific functions as well